# Browser position:absolute and decimal truncation?

Tags: html, css, decimal

I'm trying to position individual characters precisely in HTML5 using `position: absolute`.

I've tried specifying the `position` in `%` and `em`, but every browser handles the decimals differently, and depending on the zoom level, the output doesn't look great.

e.g. 12.005% and 3.003em may or may not use the decimal portion, depending on the zoom level and size relative the parent.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem across chrome/firefox? IE 9 would be nice as well.

Comment: where is your relative container? add some sample html.

Comment: From what I've seen, [CSS transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/) don't have the precision problems that the `left` and `top` styles do, and they're supported in all modern browsers (with vendor prefixes).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using fluid measurements (`%` and `em`) to handle positioning.

If you want your position to be the same (mostly) across browsers and screen sizes, then you need to use `pixels`.

BTW: you should design for the standard 100% zoom level.  Everything else is too unpredictable.